# Возможно ли проинициализировать массив в значении аргумента функции по умолчанию?

Tags: c++

Если попытаться проинициализировать массив как значение аргумента функции по умолчанию, то при компиляции возникнет ошибка

```
void tmp(int b[3]={1,2,3}){};

error: could not convert ‘{1, 2, 3}’ from ‘’ to ‘int*’
```

Однако это сработает с char*

```
void tmp(char* a="Hi"){};
```

Так возможно ли проинициализировать массив(помимо строки) в аргументах по умолчанию?

Comment: Здесь `int b[3]` - это не массив, а указатель, а `char* a="Hi"` работать не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать вот так:

```
void tmp(int b[3] = std::array<int, 3>{1,2,3}.data())
```

Если компилятор достаточно новый, то `<int, 3>` можно убрать.

И раз вам нужно значение по умолчанию, то мне что-то подсказывает, что ваша функция не меняет входной массив. Тогда `int b[3]` стоит заменить на `const int b[3]`.

---

Еще, есть вариант совсем отказаться от обычных массивов и использовать `std::array`:

```
void tmp(const std::array<int, 3> &b = {1,2,3})
```

---

> Однако это сработает с `char*`:
>
> ```
> void tmp(char* a="Hi"){};
> ```

Не работает начиная с С++11. А вот `const char *a = "Hi"` - работает.

Answer (score 2):

Простой вариант безо всякой перверсии:

```
void tmp(int * b){}

void tmp(void)
{
   int items[3]{1, 2, 3};
   tmp(items);
}
```